# No se puede convertir implicitamente de double a int. Ya existe una conversion explicita

Tags: c#, double

```
 error en la linea
```

> aristas[(i)] = Math.Sqrt(aux11 + aux12 + aux13);
>        public static void distancia(int x, int n)
>              {

```
        for ( int i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++)
        {

            noditos[i] = i;
            if (i == x)
            {
                aristas[i] = 0;
            }
            else
            {

                double aux2 = arreglo[x].gety() - arreglo[i].gety();
                double aux3 = arreglo[x].getz() - arreglo[i].getz();
                double aux1 = arreglo[x].getx() - arreglo[i].getx();
                double aux11 = Math.Pow(aux1, 2);
                double aux12 = Math.Pow(aux1, 2);
                double aux13 = Math.Pow(aux1, 2);
                aristas[(i)] = Math.Sqrt(aux11 + aux12 + aux13);
            }
        }
    }
```

Esta es parte de código:

```
class Nodo
{
public int x;
public int y;
public int z;

public Nodo(int _x, int _y, int _z)
{
    this.x = _x;
    this.y = _y;
    this.z = _z;
}
public int getx()
{
    return x;
}
public int gety()
{
    return y;
}
public int getz()
{
    return z;
}


public static int[] aristas = new int[10];
public static int[] noditos = new int[10];
public static int[,] relaciones = { { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 } };
public static int[] colorcito = new int[10];

public static List<Nodo> arreglo = new List<Nodo>();

public static void distancia(int x, int n)
{

    for ( int i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++)
    {

        noditos[i] = i;
        if (i == x)
        {
            aristas[i] = 0;
        }
        else
        {

            double aux2 = arreglo[x].gety() - arreglo[i].gety();
            double aux3 = arreglo[x].getz() - arreglo[i].getz();
            double aux1 = arreglo[x].getx() - arreglo[i].getx();
            double aux11 = Math.Pow(aux1, 2);
            double aux12 = Math.Pow(aux1, 2);
            double aux13 = Math.Pow(aux1, 2);
        //    aristas[(i)] = Math.Sqrt(aux11 + aux12 + aux13);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Comment: ¿De qué tipo es aristas? primero le asignas un entero... aristas[i] = 0; y más abajo le quieres asignar un double... aristas[(i)] = Math.Sqrt(aux11 + aux12 + aux13);

Comment: Muestra mas de tu código si puedes la función completa.

Comment: añadi parte del codigo en el siguiente comentario

Comment: Como te han dicho en el primer comentario, el problema es que `aristas` es de tipo `int`, y tu estás intentando almacenar el resultado de `Sqrt`, que lógicamente devuelve un `double`. Eso no es posible, deberás convertir ese resultado a  `int` antes de intentar almacenar ese valor.

Comment: @skar_543 si deseas agregar más información a tu pregunta usa la opción ["editar"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/199966/edit) , saludos-

Comment: Es un arreglo de enteros `int` y estas intentando guardar un decimal `double` por eso te da error.

Answer (score 1):

**Cambia**:

```
public static int[] aristas = new int[10];
```

**Por**:

```
public static double[] aristas = new double[10];
```

O **Modifica**:

```
aristas[(i)] = Math.Sqrt(aux11 + aux12 + aux13);
```

**Por:**

```
aristas[(i)] = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Sqrt(aux11 + aux12 + aux13));
```

Debes saber que te devolvera el resultado redondeado a 0 lugares despues de la coma. Si quieres redondearlo Floor o Ceiling solo debes modificarla un poco:

En caso de **Floor**:

```
aristas[(i)] = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Math.Sqrt(aux11 + aux12 + aux13)));
```

En caso de **Ceiling**:

```
aristas[(i)] = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt(aux11 + aux12 + aux13)));
```